# to which of these 'if's does the 'else' belong and why?

Tags: java

How does the Java compiler, and other compilers, handle the following scenario; where there is a nested if with no curly brackets?

```
// In Java, to which of the 'if's does this 'else' belong?
// If bOne=false and bTwo=true, will the println run?

boolean bOne = false;
boolean bTwo = true;

if (bOne)
    if (bTwo)
        bTwo = bTwo; // do nothing

else 
    System.out.println("bOne:" + bOne + ". bTwo:" + bTwo);
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else

Comment: In the same time it took you to write the question you could have just tested this yourself...

Comment: @tnw: I'm guessing the OP is asking *how* the compilers determine this. In which case, I don't think it's quite worth as many downvotes as it's getting.

Comment: @Cornstalks: I have tried to explain how a compiler does it.

Comment: et al. I was just trying to have a little fun; Lighten up why don't ya! Appreciate the answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is known as the [dangling else](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else) problem. The rule that solves this is that the `else` belongs to the closest `if`. So in that example, the `else` belongs to `if (bTwo)`.

Answer (score 6):

The `else` clause applies to the second if statement. At first, it should be read as:

```
if (bOne)
    if (bTwo)
        bTwo = bTwo; // do nothing
    else
        System.out.println("bOne:" + bOne + ". bTwo:" + bTwo);
```

And then the code should be rewritten to use curly braces.

This applies to many imperative programming languages, one notable exception being Python which has significant indentation instead of curly braces.

Answer (score 1):

It does, as some others have already said, belong to the "nearest preceding `if`". However, to AVOID this problem always use braces (and proper indentation), so that there's no need to try to figure this out by understanding how the compiler works.

By the way, the compiler solves this in this way (pseudo-code):

```
process_if()
{
    expect_token("if");
    next_token();
    expect_token("(");
    next_token();
    condition = parse_expression();
    expect_token(")");
    next_token();
    then_part = parse_statement_or_block();
    if (current_token == "else")
         else_part = parse_statement_or_block();
    else
         else_part = nothing;
}

parse_statement_or_block()
{
    if (current_token() == "{")
        do
        {
           statements += parse_statement();
        } while(current_token() != "}");
    else
        statements = parse_statement();
}

parse_statement()
{
    switch(current_token())
    {
       case "while": 
          process_while();
          break;
       case "for":
          process_for();
          break;
       case "if":
          process_if();
          break;
       .... 
   }
}
```

The way this parser works is that it reads the first if, and the `statement` inside that is another `if`, so it goes to `process_if`, takes the `condition`, the `then_part` and then checks for an `else` and takes that as the `else_part` for that `if`. Then goes back to the first if-statement and finds "no else there" (because it has already been consumed).

Actual compiler code that does exactly this:

https://github.com/Leporacanthicus/lacsap/blob/master/parser.cpp#L1854